# rbenv: version `2.2.3' is not installed (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)

Tags: ruby, deployment, rbenv, capistrano3, ruby-on-rails-4.2

When I run a deploy script, I'm having errors:

```
[cb123fad]  rbenv: version `2.2.3' is not installed (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
DEBUG [cb123fad]
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: rbenv: version `2.2.3' is not installed (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: rbenv: version `2.2.3' is not installed (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: rbenv: version `2.2.3' is not installed (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:initial
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx: Exception while executing as deploy@xx.xx.xx.xx: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: rbenv: version `2.2.3' is not installed (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

`Capfile` has `set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.3'`

Server and locally I have installed `ruby 2.2.3p173`

Changing the value from `2.2.3` to `2.2.3p173` for `set :rbenv_ruby` didn't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved the same problem setting `:rbenv_path`. Yours should be:
`set :rbenv_path, '/home/your/.rbenv/'`

This must be inside of `deploy.rb`.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately just adding `set :rbenv_path` in the `Capfile` didn't work for me. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This should be in deploy.rb, not Capfile.

Comment: This fails for me `set :rbenv_path, '~/.rbenv'` in deploy.rb.  The path is correct because if I alter it, cap immediately hits an error...  This is something introduced recently; previous deploys were working.  I really don't get it

Comment: Thanx! You made my day. I was struggling with this problem for an hour :) However, strange, cause `ruby -v` showed correct version in my case, and `bundle update` etc. worked also OK. So this seems exclusively related to deployment with Capistrano.

Comment: Like @jerome mentioned, you could abbreviate the path to a generic one: `$HOME/.rbenv`. This did work for me.

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/issues/303 and https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv/pull/59

NOTES

```
set :rbenv_path, '/home/your/.rbenv/' # works
set :rbenv_path, '~your/.rbenv/' # doesn't work
```

This issue is created due to a change in sshkit.

```
diff --git a/Gemfile.lock b/Gemfile.lock
index b85dabe..a909ee0 100644
--- a/Gemfile.lock
+++ b/Gemfile.lock
@@ -57,6 +57,7 @@ GEM
     code_metrics (0.1.3)
     coderay (1.1.0)
     colored (1.2)
+    colorize (0.7.7)
     concord (0.1.5)
       adamantium (~> 0.2.0)
       equalizer (~> 0.0.9)
@@ -215,7 +216,8 @@ GEM
     slop (3.6.0)
     spoon (0.0.4)
       ffi
-    sshkit (1.8.1)
+    sshkit (1.7.1)
+      colorize (>= 0.7.0)
       net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
       net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
     terminal-table (1.5.2)
```

Answer (score 5):

The above answere did not work for me. `gem update --system`, then `bundle install` would lead to a `fatal: No live threads left. Deadlock?` error.

```
bundle exec cap development deploy
```

completes the deployment *if* `gem 'sshkit', '~> 1.7.1'` is spedified.

However, what may occur is that `sshkit`gem might get updated to `1.8.0`or greater.  In that case,  assuming a standard Ubuntu server set-up, in deploy.rb

```
set :rbenv_path, '$HOME/.rbenv'
```

will allow deployments to complete.